# Mahout itemsimilarity - maxPrefs parameter

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

In itemsimilarity metod tere is a parameter like:

--maxPrefs (-mppu) maxPrefs                               - max number of
                                                          preferences to
                                                          consider per user or
                                                          item, users or items
                                                          with more preferences
                                                          will be sampled down
                                                          (default: 500)

How does it work exactly?
If I have 5 mln users and 5000 items and I run itemsimilarity with default maxPrefs, it consider only 500 ranks from those 5 mln or what? Is it sampling? What can I do to force calculation for all input data?

What does mean "or" in definition:
"max number of preferences to consider per user or item"

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the mailing list here: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.mahout.user/20827/match=

Basically several forms of downsampling happen to keep a high degree of quality while keeping the runtime to O(n) execution time.

Change --maxPrefs (-mppu) maxPrefs to 4000 or the highest integer value to include all.